# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'upper' while running playbook using ansible-python module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ansible

Here is code,

```
class AnsibleRunner:

    def __init__(self):
        self.variable_manager = VariableManager()
        self.loader = DataLoader()
        self.inventory = Inventory(loader=self.loader, variable_manager=self.variable_manager)
        Options = namedtuple('Options', ['listtags', 'listtasks', 'listhosts', 'syntax', 'connection','module_path', 'forks', 'remote_user', 'private_key_file', 'ssh_common_args', 'ssh_extra_args', 'sftp_extra_args', 'scp_extra_args', 'become', 'become_method', 'become_user', 'verbosity', 'check'])
        self.options = Options(listtags=False, listtasks=False, listhosts=True, syntax=False, connection='ssh', module_path=None, forks=100, remote_user='ubuntu', private_key_file=os.getcwd()+"/private-key.pem", ssh_common_args=None, ssh_extra_args=None, sftp_extra_args=None, scp_extra_args=None, become=False, become_method=None, become_user='root', verbosity=None, check=False)


    def execute_playbook(self, playbook, host, scriptname=None, command=None,
                         path=None, username=None, password=None, key=None):
        playbook_path = os.getcwd() + '/playbooks/'+playbook

        if not os.path.exists(playbook_path):
            print '[INFO] The playbook does not exist'
            sys.exit()

        script_path = None
        if scriptname is not None:
            script_path = os.getcwd() + '/' + scriptname
            if not os.path.exists(script_path):
                print '[INFO] The script does not exist'
                sys.exit()
        play_source = self.loader.load_from_file(playbook_path)
        play = Play().load(play_source[0], self.variable_manager, self.loader)
        self.variable_manager.extra_vars = {'scriptname': script_path,
                            'host': host, 'command': command, 'path': path} 

        passwords = {}
        if password is not None:
            self.loader.set_vault_password(password)

        callback = CallbackModule()
        tqm = TaskQueueManager(
            inventory=self.inventory,
            variable_manager=self.variable_manager,
            loader=self.loader,
            options=self.options,
            passwords=passwords,
            stdout_callback=callback
        )

        result = tqm.run(play)
        print result
```

Output is like :

```
PLAY [110.110.112.139]

TASK [Gathering Facts]

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'upper'

fatal: [110.110.112.139]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}
```

I tried to debug the code so will put where that host got failed due to the reason which I asked.

```
 display.debug("checking for any_errors_fatal")
```

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/strategy/linear.py(387)run()

```
failed_hosts = []
```

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/strategy/linear.py(388)run()

```
unreachable_hosts = []
```

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/strategy/linear.py(389)run()

```
for res in results:
```

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/strategy/linear.py(390)run()

```
if res.is_failed() and iterator.is_failed(res._host):

res.is_failed()
True

iterator.is_failed(res._host)
True
```

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/strategy/linear.py(391)run()

failed_hosts.append(res._host.name)

```
res._host.name
u'110.110.112.139'
```

I tried to print host value from failed host list.

Here the host stored as failed host because of NoneType Exception. Can you please check now?

This is my sample playbook which i am trying to execute,

```
---
- hosts: 110.110.112.139
  user: ubuntu
  gather_facts: no
  connection: ssh
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: "run shell script on host"
    shell: /bin/true
```

the output after putting **callback._display.verbosity = 3**

```
fatal: [110.110.112.139]: FAILED! => {
"failed": true, 
"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", 
"stdout": ""
}
```

Comment: Not possible for us to know what hasn't worked because you haven't included the traceback, only the error.

Comment: There is no `upper` function in this code and your traceback is insufficient to determine in which function it gets called.

Comment: This code uses ansible-python module so internally it runs the TaskQueueManager Class run method which uses linear strategy run method. there I get this error. You can find the code for linear strategy run method here : https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.0.0.2-1/lib/ansible/plugins/strategy/linear.py

Comment: Try to add `callback._display.verbosity = 3` after the `callback = CallbackModule()` in your code to activate verbose logs and have more info in the output. You can also run with the env-var `ANSIBLE_DEBUG=True` to activate debug output (very verbose). If it doesn't give you enough info to find out your problem, add the output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I will guess that the error is not in the runner but in the Ansible playbook itself: in a task your are trying to use `{{ somevar.upper }}` but `somevar` is `None`.

First, you need to use the jinja filter [`upper`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#upper) instead of calling the `upper method`: `{{ somevar | upper }}`.
Second, check for the value of your variable and eventually use the jinja filter [`default`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#default) to fallback to a default value: `{{ somevar | default('undefined') | upper }}`

Comment: As you suggested I tried by removing all variables from the playbook, and hard coded all values, but still I am getting same error message.

Comment: I also ran playbook manually by using ansible-playbook command. It's executing successfully so I don't think it's related to the playbook.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I only found the solution, That 
change the value for become_method in the options object.

```
become_method="sudo" 

self.options = Options(listtags=False, listtasks=False, listhosts=True, syntax=False, connection='ssh', module_path=None, forks=100, remote_user='ubuntu', private_key_file=os.getcwd()+"/private-key.pem", ssh_common_args=None, ssh_extra_args=None, sftp_extra_args=None, scp_extra_args=None, become=False, become_method="sudo", become_user='root', verbosity=None, check=False)
```

This is the final solution, thank you all for looking into this question.